# How to map array fields in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I am trying to map an array of fields in JOLT. There a four fields which I want to repeat in the array.

I tried the below spec but I am getting "Failed to transform" error in output.

Any idea on what changes I need to make in JOLT spec to get the desired output?

**What I tried in JOLT Spec-**

[image]

[image]

**Desired Output -**

[image]

**Input data-**

```
{
  "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
    "MsgData": {
      "Transaction": {
        "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
          "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": 1,
          "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "PeggyMeincke@westfieldgrp.com",
          "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
          "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "Zachary",
          "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "Engels",
          "WG_DELIVER_TO": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
          "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
          "PO_ID": 25052,
          "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
          "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
          "VNDR_LOC": 1,
          "PO_DT": "2020-01-24",
          "DB_NUMBER_BU": "",
          "DESCR_BU": "OhioFarmersInsuranceCo",
          "ADDRESS1_BU": "WESTFIELDCOMPANIES",
          "ADDRESS2_BU": "HOMEOFFICE",
          "ADDRESS3_BU": "1PARKCIRCLE",
          "ADDRESS4_BU": "",
          "CITY_BU": "WESTFIELDCENTER",
          "STATE_BU": "OH",
          "POSTAL_BU": "44251-5001",
          "COUNTRY_BU": "USA",
          "ADDRESS1_BILL": "",
          "ADDRESS2_BILL": "",
          "ADDRESS3_BILL": "",
          "ADDRESS4_BILL": "",
          "CITY_BILL": "",
          "STATE_BILL": "",
          "POSTAL_BILL": "",
          "COUNTRY_BILL": "",
          "CURRENCY_CD": "USD",
          "TAX_EXEMPT_ID": "",
          "STD_ID_NUM_VNDR": "",
          "NAME1_VNDR": "AMAZONCAPITALSERVICESINC",
          "ADDRESS1_VNDR": "410TERRYAVEN",
          "ADDRESS2_VNDR": "",
          "ADDRESS3_VNDR": "",
          "ADDRESS4_VNDR": "",
          "CITY_VNDR": "SEATTLE",
          "STATE_VNDR": "WA",
          "POSTAL_VNDR": 98109,
          "COUNTRY_VNDR": "USA",
          "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "NET30",
          "DESCR50_PAY": "Net30",
          "BUYER_ID": 1083,
          "PO_AMT_TTL": 14.99,
          "TEXT254_CC1": "",
          "TEXT254_CC2": "",
          "VNDR_UPN_FLG": "N",
          "STD_ID_NUM_VNDRGLN": "",
          "STD_ID_NUM_BILLTO": "",
          "ATTN_TO": "ZacharyEngels",
          "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
            "WG_REQ_ID": 25694,
            "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "FSSUP",
            "WG_ITEM_TYPE": 0,
            "WG_ACCOUNT": 641100,
            "WG_DEPT_ID": 30400,
            "WG_PRODUCT": "",
            "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
            "PO_ID": 25052,
            "WG_ASSET_GROUP": "",
            "WG_CAPITALIZE": "NO",
            "WG_PROFILE_ID": "",
            "WG_SPLIT_TYPE": 1,
            "WG_ASSET_LOC": "HOME",
            "WG_PROJECT": "",
            "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
            "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
            "VNDR_LOC": 1,
            "LINE_NBR": 1,
            "INV_ITEM_ID": "",
            "DESCR254_MIXED": "147-1518156-3620845,1GreenMountainCoffeeRoastersCaramelVanillaCreamKeurigSingle-ServeK-CupPods,LightRoastCoffee,32Count",
            "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "EA",
            "ITM_ID_VNDR": "B0798CX2Q9",
            "INV_ITEM_WEIGHT": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_HEIGHT": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_VOLUME": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_LENGTH": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_WIDTH": 0,
            "VNDR_CATALOG_ID": "",
            "MFG_ID": "",
            "MFG_ITM_ID": 5000196305,
            "CNTRCT_ID": "",
            "VERSION_NBR": 0,
            "CNTRCT_LINE_NBR": 0,
            "CAT_LINE_NBR": 0,
            "RELEASE_NBR": 0,
            "CANCEL_STATUS": "A",
            "UPN_ID": "",
            "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
              "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": 2,
              "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": 2,
              "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
              "PO_ID": 25052,
              "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
              "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
              "VNDR_LOC": 1,
              "LINE_NBR": 1,
              "SCHED_NBR": 1,
              "DUE_DT": "2020-01-29",
              "SHIPTO_ID": "OFIC",
              "DESCR_SHIPTO": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
              "ADDRESS1_SHIPTO": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
              "ADDRESS2_SHIPTO": "1PARKCIRCLE",
              "ADDRESS3_SHIPTO": "POBOX5001",
              "ADDRESS4_SHIPTO": "",
              "CITY_SHIPTO": "WESTFIELDCENTER",
              "STATE_SHIPTO": "OH",
              "POSTAL_SHIPTO": "44251-5001",
              "COUNTRY_SHIPTO": "USA",
              "PRICE_PO": 14.99,
              "FREIGHT_TERMS": "FOBDEST",
              "QTY_PO": 1,
              "SHIP_TYPE_ID": "BEST_WAY",
              "CANCEL_STATUS": "A",
              "ATTN_TO": "",
              "STD_ID_NUM_SHIPTO": ""
            },
            "PSCAMA": {
              "AUDIT_ACTN": "A"
            }
          },
          "PSCAMA": {
            "AUDIT_ACTN": "A"
          }
        },
        "PSCAMA": {
          "LANGUAGE_CD": "ENG",
          "AUDIT_ACTN": "A",
          "BASE_LANGUAGE_CD": "ENG",
          "MSG_SEQ_FLG": "",
          "PROCESS_INSTANCE": 1199010,
          "PUBLISH_RULE_ID": "WG_MAIN_RULE",
          "MSGNODENAME": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JOLT Spec-

```
[
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "#UPSERT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.action",
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "*": {
                            "PO_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.externalId",
                            "#APPROVED": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.status",
                            "PO_AMT_TTL": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.grossTotalAmount",
                            "FREIGHT_TERMS": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                            "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userEmailId",
                            "WG_DELIVER_TO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverTo.userEmailId",
                            "#OFIC": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.company.companyCode",
                            "BUSINESS_UNIT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.businessUnit.buCode",
                            "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.paymentTermId",
                            "#1": [
                                "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitLevel",
                                "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitType"
                            ],
                            "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddress.addressERPID",
                            "CURRENCY_CD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierCurrencyCode",
                            "@WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddressERPID",
                            "VENDOR_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierERPID",
                            "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.suppPOContactEmail",
                            "#2": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierPOContactType",
                            "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userFirstName",
                            "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userLastName",
                            "@CURRENCY_CD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.currency",
                            "@WG_DELIVER_TO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverToUser.userEmailId",
                            "#name4": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field.id",
                            "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field.type",
                            "#GL_ACCOUNT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field.name",
                            "*": {
                                "WG_REQ_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poDescription",
                                "#STANDARD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poType",
                                "LINE_NBR": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.lineNumber",
                                "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.categoryCode",
                                "WG_ITEM_TYPE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemType",
                                "MFG_ITM_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.manufacturerPartID",
                                "ITM_ID_VNDR": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.supplierPartID",
                                "WG_ACCOUNT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field.value",
                                "BUSINESS_UNIT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field.value",
                                "*": {
                                    "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddressType",
                                    "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": {
                                        "2": {
                                            "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressName",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                                            "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.city",
                                            "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.zip",
                                            "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.state",
                                            "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.country"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressCode",
                                    "FREIGHT_TERMS": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                                    "SHIPTO_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.locationCode.location.locationCode",
                                    "DUE_DT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliverOn",
                                    "@DUE_DT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliveryOn",
                                    "PRICE_PO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.marketPrice",
                                    "QTY_PO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemQuantity",
                                    "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressCode",
                                    "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressType",
                                    "#1": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.costingSplitType",
                                    "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": {
                                        "2": {
                                            "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressName",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                                            "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.city",
                                            "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.zip",
                                            "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.state",
                                            "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.country"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "integrationEntityHeader": "&3.&2.&1.&",
                        "integrationEntityDetails": {
                            "*": {
                                "externalId": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                "status": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                "poHeader": {
                                    "poDescription": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "poType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "grossTotalAmount": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "deliveryTermCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "shipToAddressType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "shipToAddress": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "company": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "businessUnit": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "locationCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "deliverOn": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "paymentTermId": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "costingSplitLevel": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "costingSplitType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "supplierAddress": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "supplierAddressERPID": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "supplierCurrencyCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "supplierERPID": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "suppPOContactEmail": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                    "supplierPOContactType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                                },
                                "items": {
                                    "item": {
                                        "lineNumber": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "requesterDetails": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "categoryCode": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "currency": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "deliverToUser": {
                                            "userEmailId": "&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                                        },
                                        "deliverOn": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "itemType": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "manufacturerPartID": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "marketPrice": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "itemQuantity": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "shipToAddressCode": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "shipToAddressType": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "costingSplitType": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "supplierPartID": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                        "validCombinations": {
                                            "itemDetails": {
                                                "validRules": {
                                                    "field": {
                                                        "id": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                                        "type": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                                        "name": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                                        "value": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "cardinality",
        "spec": {
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "*": {
                            "*": {
                                "status": "ONE",
                                "poHeader": {
                                    "*": "ONE",
                                    "company": {
                                        "*": "ONE"
                                    }
                                },
                                "items": {
                                    "item": {
                                        "costingSplitType": "ONE",
                                        "validCombinations": {
                                            "itemDetails": {
                                                "validRules": {
                                                    "field": {
                                                        "id": "ONE",
                                                        "type": "ONE",
                                                        "name": "ONE",
                                                        "value": "ONE"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "*": {
                            "*": {
                                "poHeader": {
                                    "costingSplitLevel": "=toInteger",
                                    "costingSplitType": "=toInteger",
                                    "supplierPOContactType": "=toInteger"
                                },
                                "items": {
                                    "item": {
                                        "costingSplitType": "=toInteger"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "*": {
                            "*": {
                                "*": {
                                    "*": {
                                        "product": "=divide(1,@(1,itemQuantity))",
                                        "itemTotalAmount": "=divide(@(1,marketPrice),@(1,product))"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Dear Sam, I can't understand what you want from your input. In your output you want an array of object in the `field`. please say what is the objects in `field` exact in your output. for example, i found it that your values is `641100` and `30400` that is the `WG_ACCOUNT` and `WG_DEPT_ID` in your input. please say all `keys` that you want map on it.

Comment: @MohammadReza, Please try running the above spec. I have updated it. Basically I want the output in an array like the screenshot which I have added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#UPSERT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.action",
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "PO_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.externalId",
              "#APPROVED": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.status",
              "PO_AMT_TTL": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.grossTotalAmount",
              "FREIGHT_TERMS": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
              "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userEmailId",
              "WG_DELIVER_TO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverTo.userEmailId",
              "#OFIC": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.company.companyCode",
              "BUSINESS_UNIT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.businessUnit.buCode",
              "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.paymentTermId",
              "#1": [
                                "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitLevel",
                                "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitType"
                            ],
              "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddress.addressERPID",
              "CURRENCY_CD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierCurrencyCode",
              "@WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddressERPID",
              "VENDOR_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierERPID",
              "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.suppPOContactEmail",
              "#2": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierPOContactType",
              "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userFirstName",
              "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userLastName",
              "@CURRENCY_CD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.currency",
              "@WG_DELIVER_TO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverToUser.userEmailId",
              "*": {
                "WG_REQ_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poDescription",
                "#STANDARD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poType",
                "LINE_NBR": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.lineNumber",
                "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.categoryCode",
                "WG_ITEM_TYPE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemType",
                "MFG_ITM_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.manufacturerPartID",
                "ITM_ID_VNDR": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.supplierPartID",
                "WG_ACCOUNT": {
                  "@": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].value",
                  "#name4": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].type",
                  "#GL_ACCOUNT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].name"
                },
                "BUSINESS_UNIT": {
                  "@": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].value",
                  "#name4": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].type",
                  "#GL_ACCOUNT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].name"
                },
                "*": {
                  "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddressType",
                  "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": {
                    "2": {
                      "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressName",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                      "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.city",
                      "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.zip",
                      "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.state",
                      "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.country"
                    }
                  },
                  "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressCode",
                  "FREIGHT_TERMS": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                  "SHIPTO_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.locationCode.location.locationCode",
                  "DUE_DT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliverOn",
                  "@DUE_DT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliveryOn",
                  "PRICE_PO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.marketPrice",
                  "QTY_PO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemQuantity",
                  "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressCode",
                  "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressType",
                  "#1": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.costingSplitType",
                  "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": {
                    "2": {
                      "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressName",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                      "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.city",
                      "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.zip",
                      "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.state",
                      "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.country"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "integrationEntityHeader": "&3.&2.&1.&",
            "integrationEntityDetails": {
              "*": {
                "externalId": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "status": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "poHeader": {
                  "poDescription": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "poType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "grossTotalAmount": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "deliveryTermCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "shipToAddressType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "shipToAddress": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "company": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "businessUnit": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "locationCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "deliverOn": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "paymentTermId": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "costingSplitLevel": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "costingSplitType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "supplierAddress": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "supplierAddressERPID": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "supplierCurrencyCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "supplierERPID": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "suppPOContactEmail": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "supplierPOContactType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                },
                "items": {
                  "item": {
                    "lineNumber": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "requesterDetails": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "categoryCode": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "currency": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "deliverToUser": {
                      "userEmailId": "&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                    },
                    "deliverOn": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "itemType": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "manufacturerPartID": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "marketPrice": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "itemQuantity": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "shipToAddressCode": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "shipToAddressType": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "costingSplitType": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "supplierPartID": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                    "validCombinations": {
                      "itemDetails": {
                        "validRules": {
                          "field": {
                            "*": {
                              "id": "&12.&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&",
                              "type": "&12.&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&",
                              "name": "&12.&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&",
                              "value": "&12.&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "status": "ONE",
                "poHeader": {
                  "*": "ONE",
                  "company": {
                    "*": "ONE"
                  }
                },
                "items": {
                  "item": {
                    "costingSplitType": "ONE",
                    "validCombinations": {
                      "itemDetails": {
                        "validRules": {
                          "field": {
                            "id": "ONE",
                            "type": "ONE",
                            "name": "ONE",
                            "value": "ONE"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "poHeader": {
                  "costingSplitLevel": "=toInteger",
                  "costingSplitType": "=toInteger",
                  "supplierPOContactType": "=toInteger"
                },
                "items": {
                  "item": {
                    "costingSplitType": "=toInteger"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "product": "=divide(1,@(1,itemQuantity))",
                    "itemTotalAmount": "=divide(@(1,marketPrice),@(1,product))"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

You can add your keys that you want create object from it like the below code snippet in the spec:

```json
{
  "WG_ACCOUNT": {
    "@": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].value",
    "#name4": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].id",
    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].type",
    "#GL_ACCOUNT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].name"
  },
  "BUSINESS_UNIT": {
    "@": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].value",
    "#name4": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].id",
    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].type",
    "#GL_ACCOUNT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].name"
  }
}
```

output:

```json
{
  "field": [
    {
      "id": "name4",
      "type": "AUTO_COMPLETE",
      "name": "GL_ACCOUNT",
      "value": 641100
    },
    {
      "id": "name4",
      "type": "AUTO_COMPLETE",
      "name": "GL_ACCOUNT",
      "value": "OFIC"
    }
  ]
}
```